# Symfony Yaml component: how to always wrap string in quotes when using Yaml::dump

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

When using the [Yaml::dump function](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html#writing-yaml-files) of Symfony Yaml component, the output will have some strings wrapped by single quotes and other strings not wrapped at all.

I know that [both wrapped and non-wrapped strings are correct in Yaml](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#strings), but I was wondering if there was a way to standardize the ouput (e.g. setting strings always be wrapped by single or double quotes) in order to make it consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Yaml/Yaml.html#method_dump), `dump` takes some flags. They are listed at the top of the documentation (without explanation):

- DUMP_OBJECT
- DUMP_EXCEPTION_ON_INVALID_TYPE
- DUMP_OBJECT_AS_MAP
- DUMP_MULTI_LINE_LITERAL_BLOCK

None of these have to do with quotation, so the answer is: No, it's not possible. Quotation is decided by the [Escaper](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Yaml/Escaper.html), which does not have any customization options.